# Is there any tool to convert C  to J2ME?

Tags: c, java-me

Is there any tool to convert C to J2ME? Help me by providing their list and Links.

Comment: No, there isn't such tool but a developer familiar with both languages could do the conversion.

Comment: It is very difficult. Things that you might be doing in C, may not be possible to achieve in J2ME.

Comment: Not to mention a straight conversion may not actually be possible (or be extremely difficult) if the C code depends on other C libraries that do not have bindings or ports for J2ME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are alternatives for using other programming language to program for  Java ME. There are compilers and interpreters.

This answers the question,[Cibyl](http://code.google.com/p/cibyl/) is a programming environment and binary translator that allows compiled C programs to execute on Java ME and BlackBerry phones

[MidletPascal](http://midletpascal.sourceforge.net/) - Compiles Pascal to Java ME midlet

There's another interesting tool . Alchemy-OS, it is an environment inside an environment which is Java ME,which interprets the Ether(was E) programming language

Answer (score -1):

Surely not.

J2ME requires certain methods to implemented. 
Why should any C code takes this into account?